# New Mercosul License Plates Regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex

New Mercosul License Plates have the following rules:

- Must have 7 alphanumeric digits, in which:

  - 4 are letters (A-Z)
  - 3 are digits (\d)
- Letters and Digits can be shuffled in anyway.

So the following texts are valid: AB123CD, 1A2B3CD, 123ABCD, ABCD123

And these are invalid: ABC1234D, ABCDE12, ABC123, etc

I know I can achieve this via code just checking the string size and count numbers and letters, but this problem make me wonder if that can also be achieved via Regex.

All I could think of is to generate all the possibilities like (\d{3}[A-Z]{4}) , (\d{2}[A-Z]{4}\d) and use | to join them, wich is not practical at all given the large amount of combinations, any other thoughts? Or this is just a case where Regex is a no go?

Edited after Answer:

As @stribizhev posted, this is a typical look Ahead use case.

I found this [link](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#noncap) a very useful source

And [here's an example](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html#password) on how to perform password validations using lookarounds

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can achieve that validation with the following regex:

```
^(?=(?:.*[0-9]){3})(?=(?:.*[A-Z]){4})[A-Z0-9]{7}$
```

**Explanation**:

- `(?=(?:.*[0-9]){3})` - Positive look-ahead to check for 3 digits
- `(?=(?:.*[A-Z]){4})` - Positive look-ahead to check for 4 letters
- `[A-Z0-9]{7}`- Actual string consisting of 7 alphanumeric symbols (not including `_` that is part of `\w` pattern)

An individual string should be passed to pass this test due to the anchors (`^` and `$`).

You can add case insensitive matching by adding the appropriate option.

Tested in Expresso:

[image]

Comment: I added explanation. If you know what a look-ahead is, understanding how to build such regexes comes quickly. I really like regular expressions for their compact character: other answers take several lines, mine is actually 1.

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of thing, it'd be easier to look at it from the other direction (in psedudo-code):

```
letters = regex(s/[^a-z]//, license_plate);
numbers = regex(s/[^\d]//, license_plate);

if (length(letters) == 4) && (length(numbers) == 3)) {
   plate is ok
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like no go style.

```
bool CheckPlate(string str)
{
    int let = 0;
    int dig = 0;
    foreach (ch letter in input)
    {
        let += (int) IsLetter(ch);
        dig += (int) IsDigit(ch);   
    }
    if(let == 4 && dig == 3 && str.Lenght() == 7)
        return true;
    else
      return false;
}
```